# how can i get array in proper format from this foreach and nested if condition in php?

Tags: php, arrays, vtiger

I am confused and i am new to php. I am using this code to get the list whose status is Unpaid and time taken(in days) is >30 or >60 or >90 days. If time taken is >30 days then color should be blue, >60 days then color should be orange and if >90days then color should be red. All condition are working but problem is i am not getting array in proper format how i want.

My code is

```
foreach ($listview_entries as $key => $value){
    $invoice_focus = new Invoice();
    $invoice_focus->id = $key;
    $invoice_focus->retrieve_entity_info($key, "Invoice");
    $invoicestatus = $invoice_focus->column_fields['invoicestatus'];
    $invoicedate = $invoice_focus->column_fields['invoicedate'];
    $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
    $start_date2 = strtotime($invoicedate);
    $end_date2 = strtotime($currentdate);
    $difference = $end_date2 - $start_date2;
    $days = floor($difference/86400);
    $items = array();
    $color1 = array();
    if($invoicestatus == 'Unpaid' && $days>30)
    {
        if($days>60)
        {
            if($days>90)
            {
                $milan=array($key);
                $color=array_fill_keys($milan, 'red');
                //$smarty->assign('COLOR', $color);
            }
            else
            {
                $milan=array($key);
                $color=array_fill_keys($milan, 'orange');
                //$smarty->assign('COLOR', $color);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $milan=array($key);
            $color=array_fill_keys($milan, 'blue');
            //$smarty->assign('COLOR', $color);
        }
        if(!empty($color)){
        array_push($color1,$color);
        }
        print_r($color1);
    }
    $smarty->assign('COLOR', $color1);
}
```

And i am getting output like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [89] => red ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [91] => blue ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [92] => orange ) )
```

But i want like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [89] => red ),[1] => Array ( [91] => blue ),[2] => Array ( [92] => orange ) )
```

Help me please.

Comment: Please format your code/output properly so it's easy for others to see what you're trying to do. Use `echo '<pre>',print_r($items),'</pre>';` to get a more readable output and update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Remove array reserved key form following line:

```
$milan=array($key);
```

So, put code like this

```
$color [$key] = 'red';
```

instead of

```
$milan=array($key);
$color=array_fill_keys($milan, 'red');
```

Comment: If i will remove $milan=array($key); then the function array_fill_keys will not gonna work. I works when the first argument is an array.That's why i have added in array.

Comment: try this one $milan[$key] = '';

Comment: That's not what i want. i am getting value but i just want in a single array.

Comment: try this another one if work then fine otherwise check you all condition because it messed up everything specifically loop :
$color [$key] = 'red';

Comment: Oh Thank you so much. It works. I am getting again three array but last one contains all value. Like this

Array ( [0] => Array ( [89] => red ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [89] => red [91] => blue ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [89] => red [91] => blue [92] => orange ) )

Answer (score 1):

Update to this one.

From :

```
array_push($color1,$color);
$items = array($color1);
```

To

```
array_push($color1, $color);
if(!empty($color1)) {
    $items[] = $color1;
}
```

And `$items = array()`  before loop.

Comment: Hi, I have just change my code. I am getting three array now. But i want all values in one array only.

Comment: Getting Same answer. Not getting in single array. By the way thanks for your help.

Comment: You are getting three array's because you are printing them in `fooreach`. Put `print_r($items)` after loop.

Comment: I know that. If i ll use print_r($items) after foreach loop then it returns null array.